How do I get this Geometry Nodes Hair Generator working?
I downloaded this free Geometry Nodes Hair Generator from here:

https://xeofrios.gumroad.com/l/gnhair
https://80.lv/articles/developing-a-custom-hair-creation-system-with-blender-s-geometry-nodes/
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XY5j4_BHU2A
I'm using Blender 4.2.1 but I can't get it to work. I select the hair, go into edit mode, draw the curve (like in the video tutorial), but the hair doesn't appear. What am I doing wrong?
Thanks in advance.


You edit the wrong object. Note that the Hair is a Curves object. This is a new curve type for hair curves (Blender 3.3). The Curve object (type Curve, without s) is the old Bezier/Poly/Nurbs curve type. They are similar. The Hair object has a Geometry Nodes modifier on it. If you look at the very first node on the left you see it uses the objects in the Guide collection. So, the Curve and the Mesh objects are used to create the geometry for the Hair and its own geometry gets replaced ==> edit the Curve object to create the guides, not the Hair object.

Thanks a lot friend, that solved the problem! In the video tutorial they didn't show which object they had selected, that's why I couldn't get it to work.
